# Not able run a react native project using react-native web and react-native dom

Tags: react-native, web, document

ReferenceError: Property 'document' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes
LOG  Running "PeComponents" with {"rootTag":41}
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "PeComponents" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2diD.png)

Property 'document' doesn't exist